# Gradle - How to define optional extra property in settings.gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I would like to be able to use an optional extra property in my file `build.gradle`. To do that, I have to check if the property is defined but I have the following error

> Cannot get property 'prop' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

File build.gradle

```
[...]
def my_prop=''
if(gradle.ext.prop!= null && gradle.ext.prop != '')
    my_prop=gradle.ext.prop
```

It is working with this file setting.gradle

```
gradle.ext.prop='PROP'
```

It is not working when I commented line in file setting.gradle

```
//gradle.ext.prop='PROP'
```

**How can I check in build.gradle that the `gradle.ext.prop` exists ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ext` property is of type `ExtraPropertiesExtension` : see  [this DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html)documentation.

To summarize:

- the `get(propName)` method will throw `UnknownPropertyException` if the property is not set,
- the `has(propName)` method can be used to check if a property is set before trying to access it

In your case, you could use `has(name)` method as follows

```
def my_prop = ''
if (gradle.ext.has("prop") && gradle.ext.prop != '') {
    println "Property PROP  found: $gradle.ext.prop"
    my_prop = gradle.ext.prop
    // or:  my_prop = gradle.ext('prop')
} else {
    println "Property PROP not set."
}
```